# Transparency level algorithm is so different in FireMonkey (FMX) applications under Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, firemonkey, transparency, rad-studio

I'm wondering why the transparency level algorithm is so different in FireMonkey applications under Windows and Linux.

Look at the screenshot.

Under Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS), the transparency level drops a lot at a level from 1 to 0.5 and already at a very high transparency level drops to full transparency from 0.5 to 0.
Under Windows, transparency drops evenly.

Here is the code for testing:

[image]

```
procedure TFormSimpleDraw.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  i: Integer;
  ARect: TRectF;
  AOpacity: Single;
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.White;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(TRectF.Create(0, 0, PaintBox1.Width, PaintBox1.Height), 1);

  ARect := TRectF.Create(0, 0, 40, 40);
  for I := 0 to 19 do
  begin
    AOpacity := 1 - (I / 20);
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Fill.Color := $FF3399FF;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(ARect, AOpacity);

    PaintBox1.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.FillText(ARect, FormatFloat('0.00', AOpacity),
      False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Center, TTextAlign.Center);

    ARect.Offset(40, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Try adding Skia4Delphi